# Warum wird hier "sich" verwendet?

Tags: standard-german, reflexive

> Nach 20 Jahren hätte **sich** die Natur die Städte größenteils zurückerobert.

Wofür steht *sich* hier? Ist das für das Verb oder es geht auf *die Natur* zurück? Und macht das einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung, wenn man *sich* weglässt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine Doppelung zwecks Verstärkung.

Die Natur taucht sowohl als Subjekt der Tätigkeit *zurückerobern* als auch als Dativobjekt, dem *Empfänger* des Zurückeroberten, auf.